# Chef create array of database

Tags: mysql, ruby, bash, chef-infra

Iam trying to create database with array.Iam defining array of database.and then Create database from arrays items.

This is my chef recipe for Creating database in mysql.

```
array-  database=["testy1","testy2"]
script 'set Create database ' do
  interpreter 'bash'
  user 'root'
  cwd '/tmp'
  code <<-EOH

 mysql -uroot -p\'#{pw}\' -Be\ "CREATE DATABASE #{database}"
 EOH
  not_if "mysql -u root -p\'#{pw}\' -Be\ 'SHOW DATABASES' | grep #{database};"
end
```

STDERR: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
       ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[testy1, testy2]' at line 1
       ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20190402-6843-gm0k0u" ----
       Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20190402-6843-gm0k0u" returned 1
The expected result would be creation of testy1 and test2 database.

Comment: You probably need to iterate over that database list instead of using it as-is.

Comment: Thanks but iam unable to iterate as a single values.

Comment: Hint: `database.each do |db|` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

although [database cookbook](https://github.com/chef-boneyard/database) is deprecated, you can give it a try and see whether it solves your pain. chef documentation has a tutorial for [create a web app cookbook](https://learn.chef.io/modules/create-a-web-app-cookbook/ubuntu/virtualbox/configure-mysql#/) that uses database cookbook.

regarding your issue, you should create [mysql client configuration (`my.cnf`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html), which will let you run `mysql` command without specifying the login credentials (username and password).